# Does TableLayout have Borders?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I am working on a droid application, and I am using a TableLayout but cannot get it to look how I want. I want to have 2 columns, one for the text and one for the monetary value, but I cannot get them centered (in the table) and showing up next to each other.

I am trying to get it to look like this...

http://s2.postimage.org/8wpons46m/whmcs.png

but since I cannot actually see the borders, I cannot figure out how to fix it. This is what it currently looks like...

[image]

Here is the XML layout for my Table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:background="@drawable/round_table">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Today's Income:"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="$0.00 USD"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Monthly Income:"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="$0.00 USD"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Annual Income:"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="$0.00 USD"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Just for diagnostic purposes, you can set different background colors for the views in each TableRow.

Comment: Ah that helped a lot. It looks like there is a third column that is just filling the rest of the space since my TableLayout width is fill_parent. Is there any way just to specify each TextView's width be 50% of the table width? I haven't had much luck on results searching for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use layout_weight, something on the lines of below code should work for your purpose.

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Today's Income:"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="$0.00 USD"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Monthly Income:"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="$0.00 USD"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Annual Income:"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="$0.00 USD"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Just found something that said the exact same thing and it worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: To expand on the original problem, you are starting your layout in the second column because `android:layout_column` is zero-indexed.  You're then stretching the first column that has nothing in it by setting `android:stretchColumns="0"`.  That is why everything is pushed to the right.